# Customizing the confirmation_url in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do you customize this default line generated by Devise in the mailer view?

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

I've written a method in my controller called `user_confirm`. And I have also defined a route for it. Can I get the URL to link to that method with token as the params?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this routing:

```
map.user_confirm 'confirm/:confirmation_token',
    :controller => 'confirmations', :action => 'show'
```

And this ERB:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account',
    user_confirm_url(:confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %>
```

And got this nice link:

```
http://localhost:3000/confirm/RjOnrd5yNREEDwsEfiFa
```

Comment: what changes should i do if i want the user to be redirected to https in production ?

Comment: the link i am sending now is http , and the user gets his token too but as the app is hosted on an https , it doesn't recognises the token :|

Comment: Devise 3 Update: devise now uses a shorter token which is then hashed before comparing to the database.  Your mailer link should look like this instead: `link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)`

Answer (score 7):

Its something like (in routes.rb):

```
devise_scope :user do
  match '/confirm/:confirmation_token', :to => "devise/confirmations#show", :as => "user_confirm", :only_path => false
end
```

and in views you can use something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirm_url(@resource.confirmation_token) %>
```

for Rails 3.

Comment: This seems to be a better answer than the accepted one, unless I'm misunderstanding. This one works with Rails 3.2.

Note: `"devise/confirmations#show` is explicitly saying to use the default Devise confirmations controller. If you have a custom confirmations controller, use `confirmations#show` instead, or you'll get unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

- `rails 4.0.5`
- `devise 3.2.4`

## before

**url:**

```
http://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=jevYKv1z9Pr1LsAUB2NX
```

**app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:**

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

## after

**config/routes.rb:**

```
devise_scope :user do
    get 'confirm/:confirmation_token', to: 'devise/confirmations#show'
end
```

**app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:**

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my acount', confirm_url(@token) %></p>
```

**url:**

```
http://example.com/confirm/Kezap1iutgvXyQAhyu64
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
lets say i define i named route like this.

```
map.user_confirm '/user_confirm',  :controller => 'users', :action => 'confirm'
```

all i had to do is

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirm_url(confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the devise URL will not udpate 'confirmed_at' column of the user table, what you can do is redirect the user after clicking the confirmation link:

**STEP 1** 
override the after_confirmation_path_for in your confirmations_controller:

Create a new confirmations_controller.rb in app/controllers directory:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  your_new_after_confirmation_path
 end
end
```

**STEP 2** In config/routes.rb, add this line so that Devise will use your custom ConfirmationsController. This assumes Devise operates on users table (you may edit to match yours).

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

**STEP 3** Restart the web server