# How can I use Devise's `confirmation_url` outside of a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise in a rails project. I want to pass the confirmation url to a third party. That url is produced by the expression `confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)` in the following Devise Mailer view:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

I have grepped the whole source code of Devise trying to figure out who or where is `confirmation_url` defined, but I could not find anything; it only appears on the views, so it must be dynamically generated by something.

In a regular Rails app, I can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to produce urls (ex. `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path(@user)`).

Is there anything similar I can use to invoke `confirmation_url` outside of the mailer views?

Comment: I am not sure but I think this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986445/customizing-the-confirmation-url-in-devise as you will have the confirmation token in the database then you can easily create the url. Hope this helps

Comment: It is being generated [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb), it is also available in a controller.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately I need to use it outside of the controller, too :( . Well at least I know where it is generated now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so after fighting with this for a while I decided to read the explanation near the top of this file:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb

It turns out that what Devise generates by default (at least on my app) are routes. `confirmation_url` is a *helper*, but you can still see the *routes* Devise generates:

```
rake routes | grep confirm
```

Since I am using a model called `Account` instead of `User`, that gives me this:

```
account_confirmation     POST /accounts/confirmation(.:format)  accounts/confirmations#create
new_account_confirmation GET  /accounts/confirmation/new(.:format) accounts/confirmations#new
                         GET  /accounts/confirmation(.:format)                         accounts/confirmations#show
confirm_account        PATCH  /accounts/confirmation(.:format)                         accounts/confirmations#update
```

By looking at the generated emails I confirmed that the emails looked like this:

```
http://myserver.com/accounts/confirm?confirmation_token=xxxx
```

This is the third route on the listing above - the second GET. For reasons unknown to me, rails does not print the name of show-like routes, but you can deduce it from the POST at the top; the route is named `account_confirmation`. So now I can use the rails url helper to generate the url myself:

```
Rails.application
     .routes.url_helpers
     .account_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: account.confirmation_token)
```

Which will return an url like the one above. Remember to replace `account` by `user`, or whatever else you are authenticating with Devise.