# why devise is generating this format of confirmation URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable, devise-token-auth

devise keep on generating this format of `confirmation URL`

```
http://something.com/users/confirmation/divyanshu-rawat?confirmation_token=CV3zV1wAWsb3RokHHEKN
```

I don't know why it is not generating something like this.

```
http://something.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=CV3zV1wAWsb3RokHHEKN
```

This is how my `confirmation_instructions.html.haml` looks like.

```
%p Welcome #{@resource.first_name}!
%p You can confirm your account email through the link below:
%p= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token)
```

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986445/customizing-the-confirmation-url-in-devise

Comment: @GaganGupta That link was helpful, really :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Devise** gem, routes for confirmation are created as below,

```
#  # Confirmation routes for Confirmable, if User model has :confirmable configured
#  new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"new"}
#      user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"show"}
#                        POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"create"}
```

So if you want to create url like,

```
http://something.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=CV3zV1wAWsb3RokHHEKN
```

**Use**

```
user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: @resource.confirmation_token)`
```

**Instead of**

```
user_confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @resource.confirmation_token)`
```

Also check **routes.rb**

If you want to pass *user_name* or *name* db attribute of `@resource` in confirmation url (as you asked by passing 'divyanshu-rawat' in your url), You can create own custom route which will point to same controller & action as below,

```
  # config/routes.rb
  devise_for :users

  as :user do
    get  '/users/confirmation/:name' => "devise/confirmations#show", as: 'user_confirm'
  end
```

And if in your case, @resource.user_name = 'divyanshu-rawat', update `confirmation_instructions.html.haml` as below,

```
%p Welcome #{@resource.first_name}!
%p You can confirm your account email through the link below:
%p= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirm_url(name: @resource.user_name, confirmation_token: @resource.confirmation_token)
```

Which will produce url like,

```
http://something.com/users/confirmation/divyanshu-rawat?confirmation_token=CV3zV1wAWsb3RokHHEKN
```